# IndexError: list index out of range Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

I am going through chapter 8 of Python for Informatics and have been asked for an exercise to rewrite the following function:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    #print 'Debug:', words
    if len(words) == 0:
        continue
    if words[0] != 'From':
        continue
    print words[2]
```

I was asked to rewrite it using a single compound `if` statement, so I wrote the following:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
#count = 0 <-- not even sure why this is in the orginal
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    print 'Debug:', words
    if len(words) == 0 and words[0] != 'From':
        continue
    print words[2]
```

The first function works just fine, but the second gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ch8.py", line 258, in <module>
    print words[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not understand why what I wrote is returning the error, as far as I can tell I am doing the same exact thing, but apparently I am wrong, I just don't understand why. Maybe there is a subtle issue that I am just not picking up on.

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

Instructions 'use a compound logical expression using the `and` logical operator with a single `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original code

```
    if len(words) == 0:
        continue
    if words[0] != 'From':
        continue
```

You reach `continue` in *either* case. Therefore the single line version should be

```
if len(words) == 0 or words[0] != 'From':
                #  ^ or, not and
    continue
```

If you need to use `and`, more refactoring is needed, switching the `print` and (now-implicit) `continue` and reversing the tests:

```
if len(words) > 0 and words[0] == 'From':
    print words[2]
```

Comment: works great but I am instructed to use a `and` operator unless it's a book typo

Answer (score 2):

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    print 'Debug:', words
    if len(words) == 0 or words[0] != 'From':
        continue
    print words[2]
```

Change `and` to `or`.

Comment: works great but I am instructed to use a `and` operator unless it is a typo in the book